# Mess with the folder structure

Tags: php, symfony

I can divide the project I'm working on into three separate folders - ADMIN, CONTENT, SYSTEM. Each of them would be using a couple of symfony bundles.

This makes two problems - if user downloads the project he first sees folders like app, src, web...And if he goes into the proper src folder all the names have bundle at the end. Though the second thing is acceptable, the first one is pretty annoying.

Instead of getting the first architectural overview of the project, the user gets a lot of irrelevant-for-him folders.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I don't see the problem - it's Symfony who has to deal with fies, not the user.

Answer (score 2):

The structure is clear. As the user shouldn't dive into the code! And if he want, he has to understand symfony.

And none of the folders is irrelevant or annoying. In app/config lives the parameters.yml, the only may relevant file for the user (mostly for configuring the database). src is your code, not important for a user. vendor are all the 3rd party stuff, also not important. web is important, as the DocumentRoot of the webserver should point to it. Pretty understandable.